# vCenter Server update procedure

Tags: vmware-vcenter

In the process of making a decision of implementing a FT storage in your environment that is running vCenter Server 6.0  4541947, I wanted to upgrade vCenter prior to implementing the solution.

Our infrastructure is based on 3xR730 with 3x400gb SSD and 6x1.6 15k NLSAS HDD drives and we are running around 70 VMs.

Would it be possible to keep both of the VMFS 5 and VMFS 6?

Comment: Please add more details.

+1 to hesoyam. From my perspective, the no issues running updates on your setup. Personally, I applied update vCenter 6.0 to 6.5 according to the article smoothly.

Be sure you have done backups before start update process.

Comment: the article - https://miketabor.com/upgrade-vcenter-server-appliance-6-0-to-6-5/

Answer (score 7):

There are just several aspects which need to be considered, 
**the compatibility of your hardware** (no issues with that from what I can see), **another product compatibility** (unaware of any additional products you have setup at the moment) **and the transition to the new VMFS datastore format**. From the looks of it, the biggest part of the process is the **migration of data between the previous datastore format and the new**.